# Mimic "Mute" functionality that keeps muted conversations out of the Inbox but using a custom label

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

In Gmail I have two labels, **`Followup`** and **`Hold`**. **`Followup`** is to label messages where I still need to take some action. **`Hold`** is for messages where I'm waiting for something.

I try to keep my Inbox empty at all times. As emails come in, I archive them after first applying one of the two labels if they apply.

When I get a new message in a conversation I've already archived and labeled **`Followup`**, the conversation returns to my Inbox in addition to the **`Followup`** folder.

I would prefer if it behaved more like Gmail's mute function. If I mute a conversation, all future replies stay out of my Inbox. How can I mimic the same behavior with my two custom labels?

Answer (score 0):

## Archive Gmail Threads by Label

Here's a simple time-based script that will check for threads with any of the labels in the array **`labelNames`**. For example, **`Followup`** and **`Hold`**.

If any threads are found with those labels, it will archive them if any are in the Inbox after first reapplying the label to ensure all messages in the thread are properly labeled.

The script will work whether **conversation mode** is on or off.

It should be noted that the script is written with the expectation that there **won't be thousands of threads** with those label names.

## Main Script

```
//  Archives Gmail threads by label and reapplies label 
//  to thread at the same time.


const labelNames = [ "Followup", "Hold" ]; 

function archiveGmailThreadsByLabel() {

    for (let i = 0; i < labelNames.length; i++) {  
        let name = labelNames[i]; 
        let label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);
        
        if (label) {
            let threads = label.getThreads();
            let len = threads.length;
            let counter = 0;
            
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
                let thread = threads[i]; 

                if (thread.isInInbox()) {
                    counter += 1;
                    thread.addLabel(label);
                    thread.moveToArchive();
                }
            }
            console.log("\""+name+"\" ["+len+" Thread"+(len == 1?"":"s")+
                (len ? "; "+ counter +" Archived]" :"]"));
    
        } else {
          console.log("\""+name+"\" [**Label doesn't exist**]")}
    }
}
```

## Time-Based Trigger Script

You need to manually install a time-based trigger or you can add the additional code below to the existing script and then install the trigger by running the **`install_trigger`** function from the script editor.

The schedule is currently set to 5 minutes using **`everyMinutes(5)`**.  Valid values for **`everyMinutes()`** are **`1`, `5`, `10`, `15`, `30`**. See [Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) for other time-based options.

```
function install_trigger(){ 
    delete_triggers()   // avoids duplicates
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("archiveGmailThreadsByLabel").timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
}

function delete_triggers(){
    ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
}
```

[image: Run > install_trigger]